# Meteor.users.allow never fires, but Meteor.users.deny works

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a Meteor application with autopublish removed.

In this app, I want to allow administrators to crud any user, but other users should only be able to update their own. With a simple Meteor.users.allow, the update function never gets called (that I can tell), but if I user Meteor.users.deny and reverse the logic, it works fine.

There is only one Meteor.users.allow function in my app. I can live with using deny, but can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong with allow?

My allow function, which never logs anything:

```
console.log("Setting Meteor.users.allow");
Meteor.users.allow({
  insert: function (userId, doc) {
    // only admin can insert 
    var u = Meteor.users.findOne({_id:userId});
    return (u && u.isAdmin);
  },
  update: function (userId, doc, fields, modifier) {
    console.log("user "+userId+"wants to modify doc"+doc._id);
    if (userId && doc._id === userId) {
      console.log("user allowed to modify own account!");
      // user can modify own 
      return true;
    }
    // admin can modify any
    var u = Meteor.users.findOne({_id:userId});
    return (u && u.isAdmin);
  },
  remove: function (userId, doc) {
    // only admin can remove
    var u = Meteor.users.findOne({_id:userId});
    return (u && u.isAdmin);
  }
});
```

My deny function, which logs and works:

```
console.log("Setting Meteor.users.deny");
Meteor.users.deny({
  insert: function (userId, doc) {
    // only admin can insert 
    var u = Meteor.users.findOne({_id:userId});
    return !(u && u.isAdmin);
  },
  update: function (userId, doc, fields, modifier) {
    console.log("user "+userId+"wants to modify doc"+doc._id);
    if (userId && doc._id === userId) {
      console.log("user allowed to modify own account!");
      // user can modify own 
      return false;
    }
    // admin can modify any
    var u = Meteor.users.findOne({_id:userId});
    return !(u && u.isAdmin);
  },
  remove: function (userId, doc) {
    // only admin can remove
    var u = Meteor.users.findOne({_id:userId});
    return !(u && u.isAdmin);
  }
});
```

Comment: Is the data you are modifying in the user profile?  There is a default allow that lets any client modify its own profile.  Has the doc._id that fails been published to the admin user?  I think I also hit a default deny rule once trying to update data which was not published to that client.

Comment: This is very risky. If I can modify my profile and set `isAdmin` to true, I'll become admin! You should deny actions on field `isAdmin`!

Answer (score 1):

Did you make sure to put your Meteor.users.allow code in the server?

I was running into the same problem while using an allow in the client and not the server code.

Answer (score 0):

The first allow moves it through.  Like or clause.  Most deny routines never complain, so it has to go through them all - maybe the last one will fail.  Now, you could say it could stop on the first deny, but they needed something that would always be fired, so they didn't optimize that code.

You do need to have some more secure version of this code:

```
ok = ->
  true

Agents.allow
  insert: ok 
  update: ok
  remove: ok  # authorize.authorsAndAdmins
```

Comment: I should have said, the allow function doesn't fire even when there is no deny function. Or at least, none that I have created. Does a hidden default deny somewhere override my allow?

Comment: Any deny would prevent allow, yes.  As would another allow.  Have you set up permissions and removed autopublish and insecure from meteor packages?  Like: (bad code but good example) ok = ->
  true

Agents.allow
  insert: ok 
  update: ok
  remove: ok  # authorize.authorsAndAdmins

Comment: You've probably answered my question, and I'm just not quick enough to get it. autopublish and insecure are not in the app. My allow clause is basically like you suggest, but it never gets hit, even when I don't have a deny. Can you clarify your ok = -> true example?

Comment: Sorry, my last comment seems random!  I now suspect u.isAdmin fails, so a deny actually is kicking in.  Quick test:  return false in the deny.  You know the user rec is protected, and values you set on it need to be explicitly added?  I can find that if you didn't know.